# Analyst vs analyzer/analyser?

Tags: meaning, differences, word-usage

What are the scenarios where the meanings of these differ? What is the difference between their meanings and if any, why? I have observed that the term 'analyst' is specifically used in cases of humans. 'Analyser/analyzer' is used with humans and with others also, such as 'lexical analyzer' in computer science. Also when used with humans, 'analyzer' is used to describe some one's skills/ability (such as in resumes 'good analyzer' can be seen. Whereas the word 'analyst' is mostly seen in job descriptions. Can anyone help me understand the similarities and differences in these two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [**Dictionary.com**](http://dictionary.reference.com/), and excellent online dictionary that draws from several good traditional sources:

**`analyzer:`**
A person, machine, or device that analyzes.

**`analyst:`**
A person who analyzes or who is skilled in analysis.

The definition of `analyst`stresses two points: A **person**, and **skilled**.

That's why you find `analyst`in job descriptions - it denotes a person with a specific skillset: Good, trained, skilled at analysis. You can analyze, but not be good at it - that will certainly make you an `analyzer`, but not necessarily an `analyst`.

Another way to think of it perhaps, is that an`analyst`achieves results and conclusions from their actions as an`analyzer`: An `analyst` does not just engage in the act of analyzing (that's an `analyzer`) , but produces an `analysis`- a result.